# a norm is symmetric if and only if it is unitarily invariant

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

how can I prove this :
A norm on $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ is symmetric if and only if it is
unitarily invariant  ?

**My attempt**

I know that a symmetric norm is a norm which verifies : $$N(ABC)\leq N(B)N(A)N(C) $$ and I know that a norm is unitarily invariant if it verifies for unitary matrix $Q ,Q'$  $ N(QAQ') =N(A) $  but I don't know how to prove the statement.

Comment: What does it mean for a norm to be symmetric? Does it mean $\lVert A\rVert = \lVert A^\ast\rVert$ for all $A$, where $A^\ast$ is the conjugate transpose of $A$?

Answer (score 0):

[image: this is from R. Bhatia book page 94]
This is from R. Bhatia book page 94.
The definition you wrote of the symmetric norm is wrong. This is the true definition and that’s the proof